# Azure SSL certificate not syncing after rekey operation

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have an app service certificate and noticed that some macOS and iOS browsers are not trusting it anymore (as per the advisory Microsoft sent on April). I proceeded to rekey and sync the certificate. Rekey was successful, I can see a new certificate thumbprint, however when I click "Sync" button, I still see "Linked private certificates are out of sync" message, and the linked certs have the old thumbprint. I tried deleting the certificate from the app service and reimporting it from keyvault manually with no luck. I have waited about 10 hours so far, and heard that there was a 48 hour wait time for the automated job to sync the certs. Just wondering why the manual sync is not working and how I can force it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing of certificates after rekeying is automatic for Azure. However, the manual process takes a minimum of 24hrs before syncing. Furthermore, when you try to delete a certificate, you receive the following error message:

"Unable to delete the certificate because it is currently being used in a TLS/SSL binding. The TLS binding must be removed before you can delete the certificate."

**Cause**
This problem might occur if another app uses the certificate.

**Solution**
Remove the TLS binding for that certificate from the apps. Then try to delete the certificate. If you still can't delete the certificate, clear the internet browser cache and reopen the Azure portal in a new browser window. Then try to delete the certificate.

You can read [this Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-domain-ssl-certificates)